# How to create Bootstrap4 navbar with menus and sub menus with JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a JSON string from which I want to create a Bootstrap 4 navbar. As I am new to JavaScript and jQuery I am not getting an idea of how to achieve that.

Here is my JSON data:

```
var data = {
    "Setup":
        [
            {  "type": "Submenu-1" },

            {  "type": "submenu-2" }
        ],
    "Report":
        [
            {  "type": "subreport-1" },

            {  "type": "subreport-2" }
             ],
    "logout":
        []

};
```

I want to have a navbar like

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
  data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
  aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
  aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
   <!-- Links -->
   <!-- DropDown -->

   <!-- setup -->

   <li class="nav-item dropdown">

     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbardrop"
      data-toggle="dropdown"> Setup </a>
    
    
    <div id="drop" class="dropdown-menu">
     
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> submenu-1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> submenu-2</a>
    
    </div></li>
   
   <li class="nav-item dropdown">
     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop"
      data-toggle="dropdown"> Report </a>
    
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
    
     
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="">subreport-1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="">subreport-2</a>
    

    </div></li>
   

   <li class="nav-item">
     
    <a class="nav-link" href="">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </nav>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
 <script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I don't know how I can achieve this from JavaScript or jQuery - how can I achieve this?

My JSON data is dynamic; it can vary from 3 menus to 6-7, and the same for submenus also.

Comment: @adiga i have tried this   "  for (var i in data) {
      $('.nav-tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#' + i + '" aria-controls="' + i + '" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">' + i + '</a></li>');
    
      var div = '<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="' + i + '">';
      
      for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        var obj = data[i][j];
        div += '<div id="' + obj.id + '">' + obj.type + '</div>';
     }
     $('.tab-content').append(div);
}"   i ahve found this one from google only but its only working for ul tag and not for nav

Comment: Please see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/saslam/vepeLmm0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope it will help to generate dynamic navbar from Json data.

```js
var data = {
    "Setup":
        [
            {  "type": "Submenu-1", "link" : "https://www.google.com" },
            {  "type": "submenu-2", "link" : "https://www.google.com" }
        ],
    "Report":
        [
            {  "type": "subreport-1", "link" : "https://www.google.com" },
            {  "type": "subreport-2", "link" : "https://www.google.com" }
        ],
    "logout":
        []

};

$(document).ready(function() {
 
 for (var item in data) { 
     var _menu = "";
        var _submenuData = data[item];
        if(_submenuData.length > 0) {
         var _submenu = "";
            
         for(var i = 0; i < _submenuData.length; i++) {
             _submenu += "<a class='dropdown-item' href='" + _submenuData[i]["link"] + "'>" + _submenuData[i]["type"] + "</a>";
        }
        
        _menu = "<li class='nav-item dropdown'>"
          + "<a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' href='' id='navbardrop' data-toggle='dropdown'> " + item + " </a>"
                + "<div id='drop' class='dropdown-menu'>"
                + _submenu
    + "</div>"
                + "</li>";
        }
        else {
         _menu = "<li class='nav-item'>"
          + "<a class='nav-link' href=''> " + item + " </a>"
                + "</li>";
        }
        
        $("#navbarId").append(_menu);
    }

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
 <script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
  data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
  aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
  aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul id="navbarId" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  </ul>
 </div>
 </nav>
```

Comment: hey it is the solution i was looking for thanxx :)... i have a small question to ask may i ?

Comment: Yes, ask question

Comment: like in my json currently i am calling only sub menu name ...now what if i have to provide  a link to submenu-1...should i have to call that link in my json?..like some one click on submenu then it should go to that link

Comment: I updated the snippet, check it you will get how to add link(url) to sub menus